# gsub issue with awk (gawk)

Tags: windows, awk

I need to search a text file for a string, and make a replacement that includes a number that increments with each match.

The string to be "found" could be a single character, or a word, or a phrase.

The replacement expression will not always be the same (as it is in my examples below), but will always include a number (variable) that increments.

For example:

1) I have a test file named "data.txt". The file contains:

```
Now is the time
for all good men
to come to the
aid of their party.
```

2) I placed the awk script in a file named "cmd.awk". The file contains:

```
/f/ {sub ("f","f(" ++j ")")}1
```

3) I use awk like this:

```
awk -f cmd.awk data.txt
```

In this case, the output is as expected:

```
Now is the time
f(1)or all good men
to come to the
aid of(2) their party.
```

The problem comes when there is more than one match on a line. For example, if I was searching for the letter "i" like:

```
/i/ {sub ("i","i(" ++j ")")}1
```

The output is:

```
Now i(1)s the time
for all good men
to come to the
ai(2)d of their party.
```

which is wrong because it doesn't include the "i" in "time" or "their".

So, I tried "gsub" instead of "sub" like:

```
/i/ {gsub ("i","i(" ++j ")")}1
```

The output is:

```
Now i(1)s the ti(1)me
for all good men
to come to the
ai(2)d of thei(2)r party.
```

Now it makes the replacement for all occurrences of the letter "i", but the inserted number is the same for all matches on the same line.

The desired output should be:

```
Now i(1)s the ti(2)me
for all good men
to come to the
ai(3)d of thei(4)r party.
```

Note: The number won't always begin with "1" so I might use awk like this:

```
awk -f cmd.awk -v j=26 data.txt
```

To get the  output:

```
Now i(27)s the ti(28)me
for all good men
to come to the
ai(29)d of thei(30)r party.
```

And just to be clear, the number in the replacement will not always be inside parenthesis. And the replacement will not always include the matched string (actually it would be quite rare).

The other problem I am having with this is...

I want to use an awk-variable (not environment variable) for the "search string", so I can specify it on the awk command line.

For example:

1) I placed the awk script in a file named "cmd.awk". The file contains something like:

```
/??a??/ {gsub (a,a "(" ++j ")")}1
```

2) I would use awk like this:

```
awk -f cmd.awk -v a=i data.txt
```

To get the output:

```
Now i(1)s the ti(2)me
for all good men
to come to the
ai(3)d of thei(4)r party.
```

The question here, is how do I represent the the variable "a" in the /search/ expression ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

awk version:

```
awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)$i="(" ++k ")" $i}1' FS=i OFS=i
```

Comment: I had to play around with the quotes to make it work on Windows command line, this is what I came up with: `awk "BEGIN{FS=\"i\"; OFS=\"i\"; k=0}{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++)$i=\"(\" ++k \")\" $i}1" "data.txt"`. Can you explain a bit why some uses of variable "i" are preceeded by "$" ("$i"), and some are not ?

Comment: Variables do not use a $-sign, but the fields ($1, $2, .. ) do and so does the record itself ( $0 ). But if i=5 for example, then $i means $5.

Comment: @KevinFegan don't use awk scripts on the command line in Windows or you will have quoting and other problems as you found. Instead put the script in a file named, say, "foo.awk" and run it as awk -f foo.awk data.txt. You might want to look into installing cygwin to avoid the nightmare that is Windows for scripting.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks, I agree. As shown in the example I gave in my question, I usually put the awk script in a file and run awk with `-f` (on Windows). Except for very-very simple cases.

Answer (score 2):

`gensub()` sounds ideal here, it allows you to replace the Nth match, so what sounds like a solution is to iterate over the string in a `do{}while()` loop replacing one match at a time and incrementing `j`. This simple `gensub()` approach won't work if the replacement does not contain the original text (or worse, contains it multiple times), see below.

So in awk, lacking perl's "`s///e`"  evaluation feature, and its stateful regex `/g` modifier (as used by Steve) the best remaining option is to break the lines into chunks (*head*, *match*, *tail*) and stick them back together again:

```
BEGIN { 
    if (j=="") j=1
    if (a=="") a="f"
}
match($0,a) { 
    str=$0; newstr=""
    do {
         newstr=newstr substr(str,1,RSTART-1) # head
         mm=substr(str,RSTART,RLENGTH)        # extract match
         sub(a,a"("j++")",mm)                 # replace
         newstr=newstr mm 
         str=substr(str,RSTART+RLENGTH)       # tail
    } while (match(str,a))
    $0=newstr str     
}
{print}
```

This uses `match()` as an epxression instead of a `//`  pattern so you can use a variable. (You can also just use "`($0 ~ a) { ... }`", but the results of `match()` are used in this code, so don't try that here.)

You can define `j` and `a` on the command line.

`gawk` supports `\y` which is the equivalent of perlre's `\b`, and also supports `\<` and `\>` to explictly match the start and end of a word, just take care to add extra escapes from a unix command line (I'm not quite sure what Windows might require or permit).

---

**Limited `gensub()` version**

As referenced above:

```
match($0,a) {
    idx=1; str=$0
    do {
        prev=str
        str=gensub(a,a"(" j ")",idx++,prev)
    } while (str!=prev && j++)
    $0=str
}
```

The problems here are:

- if you replace substring "`i`" with substring "`k`" or "`k(1)`" then the `gensub()` index for the next match will be off by 1. You could work around this if you either know that in advance, or work backward through the string instead.
- if you replace substring "`i`" with substring "`ii`" or "`ii(i)`" then a similar problem arises (resulting in an infinite loop, because `gensub()` keeps finding a new match)

Dealing with both conditions robustly is not worth the code.

Comment: You said `This won't work if the replacement does NOT contain the original text`. Can you explain why, and provide a `gensub()` example ?  Also, in a case where I wanted to replace only the first match on a line, can you describe how I can represent the the variable "a" in the /search/ expression like: `/??a??/ {sub (a,a "(" ++j ")")}1` ?

Comment: `gensub()` added. Use `match() {...}` as above, or since "`//`" is really equivalent to `($0 ~ //)` you can use `($0 ~ a) {...}` instead, where `a` is the regex variable (use no leading/trailing `/` though in the variable). If you don't need capturing or anything else, @Scrutinizer's approach is *far* simpler.

Comment: `if you replace "i" with "k(1)"` - I don't see where you define variable "k"... or is "k" just a string literal ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying this can't be done using `awk`, but I would strongly suggest moving to a more powerful language. Use `perl` instead.

To include a count of the letter `i` beginning at 26, try:

```
perl -spe 's:i:$&."(".++$x.")":ge' -- -x=26 data.txt
```

This could also be a shell var:

```
var=26
perl -spe 's:i:$&."(".++$x.")":ge' -- -x=$var data.txt
```

Results:

```
Now i(27)s the ti(28)me
for all good men
to come to the
ai(29)d of thei(30)r party.
```

---

To include a count of specific words, add word boundaries (i.e. `\b`) around the words, try:

```
perl -spe 's:\bthe\b:$&."(".++$x.")":ge' -- -x=5 data.txt
```

Results:

```
Now is the(6) time
for all good men
to come to the(7)
aid of their party.
```